# semanticContentAttribute is not working

Tags: ios, swift, localization

In my app there is three languages i.e. **ar** , **fr** & **en**. And Based on the app language is changing the app language and semantics.

In my app, app language is properly changed as per the requirement but its semantics is not changing.

Here is the tried code what I am doing when user changed the language.

```
let cur_lang = Localize.currentLanguage()
    print("current lang; \(cur_lang)")
    if cur_lang == "ar"{
        UIView.appearance().semanticContentAttribute = .forceRightToLeft
    }
    else{
        UIView.appearance().semanticContentAttribute = .forceLeftToRight
    }

    imgView.image = UIImage(named: "flag".localized())
    lblTitle.text = "Title".localized()
    lblDescription.text = "Description".localized()
    lblName.text = "Name".localized()
    tfName.text = "textName".localized()
```

Here is the gif of the screen.

[image]

**Required Output:**

[image]

> Edit

If I take all contents in a view , then it is working as expected  but [natural text alignment](https://useyourloaf.com/blog/natural-text-alignment-for-rtl-languages/) and navigation bar is still uneffected.

It is not possible to flip each and every view as it may reduce app performance if there is  complex layout.

So I tried `self.view.semanticContentAttribute = .forceRightToLeft` and it does not make any difference.

My every UI component have leading trailing not left right and **respect language direction** is also selected.

[image]

Comment: `UIAppearance` doc: "iOS applies appearance changes when a view enters a window, it doesn’t change the appearance of a view that’s already in a window. To change the appearance of a view that’s currently in a window, remove the view from the view hierarchy and then put it back."

Comment: @Larme Can you please let me know how to do this. I already tired of google searches I didn't found any solution.

Comment: You need to "reload" the view (remove them and reenter) if you want `UIView.appearance().semanticContentAttribute = ...` to work.

Comment: @Larme I already tried `UIView.appearance().semanticContentAttribute` , if you see my code above. It does not make any change in UI. And i din't fount any other way to do this. Now either I have to use `pseudo language` (it does not make any sense in real - app) or change  each and every UI with loop (it reduces app performance).

Comment: you either do loop or reload the VC

Comment: @Sh_Khan I already know this solution before posting the question. I wanted avoid this bcz if UI is complex and heavy then it is not a good practice (think about it). second thing is that natural text alignment is not working expected and at last navigation controller still be at same position (button).

Comment: in most cases you don't have to flip all the layout it's always some part , so hold a reference to the parent view of that part and control it's semantic & change the alignment manually if ---- selection is not working

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. First step, you need to apply the semantic content attribute as mentioned in the other answers.

   ```
   // get current language using your 'Localize' class
   let locale = Localize.currentLanguage()
   UIView.appearance().semanticContentAttribute = locale == "ar" ? .forceRightToLeft : .forceLeftToRight
   ```

   However, this alone would not work because based on [Apple's Doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiappearance):

   > iOS applies appearance changes when a view enters a window, it doesn’t change the appearance of a view that’s already in a window. To change the appearance of a view that’s currently in a window, remove the view from the view hierarchy and then put it back.
2. The second step is in the doc itself. You only need to *remove the view from the view hierarchy and then put it back.*

   ```
   let window = self.view.superview
   self.view.removeFromSuperview()
   window?.addSubview(self.view)
   ```

   *Note: Since `self.view` is already instantiated and you're only removing it from the view hierarchy and putting it back, you don't need to worry about recreating the view from scratch.* :)

[Voila!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cHrUj.gif)

Answer (score 7):

**Swift 4.2, 5.0**

```
        if isArabic {
            UIView.appearance().semanticContentAttribute = .forceRightToLeft
            UIButton.appearance().semanticContentAttribute = .forceRightToLeft
            UITextView.appearance().semanticContentAttribute = .forceRightToLeft
            UITextField.appearance().semanticContentAttribute = .forceRightToLeft
        } else {
            UIView.appearance().semanticContentAttribute = .forceLeftToRight
            UIButton.appearance().semanticContentAttribute = .forceLeftToRight
            UITextView.appearance().semanticContentAttribute = .forceLeftToRight
            UITextField.appearance().semanticContentAttribute = .forceLeftToRight
        }
```

Answer (score 4):

Another way to solve this problem is put your condition code in

```
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
        if Language.language == .arabic {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.inputTextField.semanticContentAttribute = .forceRightToLeft
                self.inputTextField.textAlignment = .right
            }

        } else {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.inputTextField.semanticContentAttribute = .forceRightToLeft
                self.inputTextField.textAlignment = .left
            }
        }
    }
```

Simply work ;)

Answer (score 1):

Semantic content attribute must be applied to the direct parent of the view you want to flip when change the language , so do this for the parent view of flag imageV and the 2 labels

```
self.directParentView.semanticContentAttribute = .forceRightToLeft
```

Comment: So you are saying I have to apply `semanticContentAttribute ` on each and every `uiview`?

Comment: even [natural text aligment](https://useyourloaf.com/blog/natural-text-alignment-for-rtl-languages/) is also not working.

Comment: one fast way is to loop through all subviews for the self.view and change there semantic , also for every subviews inside the subview , i mean recursion

Comment: i will make a demo for your case

Comment: If I take all contents in a view , then it is working as expected (I already tried) but natural text alignment and navigation bar is still uneffected.

Comment: they must have leading & trailing constraints to be flipped

Answer (score 0):

for textFields - use can use extension like this:

```
extension UITextField {
 open override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        if UserDefaults.languageCode == "ar" {
            if textAlignment == .natural {
                self.textAlignment = .right
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Its not all about text, its UI. Every thing must be from right to left